# WebStorm AngularJS html autocompletion

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Can I setup WebStorm to autocomplete "Controllers.My" and "c1.test"?

```
    // TypeScript code    
    module Controllers
    {
        export class My
        {
            test: string;
            constructor()
            {
                this.test = "ups";
            }
        }
    }

    // html
    <div ng-controller="Controllers.My as c1">
        <input ng-model="c1.test"> {{c1.test}} 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try [WebStorm 8 RC](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+8+EAP) - completion works there. See also http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/01/webstorm-8-eap/

Comment: It does it indeed. Although it could not pick up new "as syntax" - underlines c1 as "Unresolved type c1" and does not give intellisense on c1 or scope properties.

Comment: please vote for [WEB-11544](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11544) to be notified on any progress

Comment: Actually, as I've found out, if I register My class as an angular controller WebStorm is able to figure out the type of c1 and starts providing intellisense for {{c1.test}} property. The only thing missing is intellisense inside ng-model which I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

select this code and

Use `File -> Settings -> Live Template` option and

click `+` button in top right corner and chose `1.Live Template`

you will be shown a panel there type your `abbrevation` field **eg:** "myfn" and in `Template text` field type the template you want

**eg:**

```
function My (){

}
```

and save it,
now every time you type **myfn** and hit `tab` button, you will get the above template

And similarly you can add **html** templates , or any language supported by webstorm

Comment: Although useful it's not exactly what I wanted - define a new class and see it immediately in intellisense.